# Why is __radd__ not called for the same class in Python?

Tags: python

I thought returning `NotImplemented` from `__add__` will pass to `__radd__` under all circumstances, but apparently this is not true if it's the same class?

```
class A:
    def __add__(self, other):
        print("add")
        return NotImplemented

    def __radd__(self, other):
        print("radd")
        return 100

A()+A()

# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'A' and 'A'
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reflected methods (like `__radd__`) are [only used](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__)

> if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation *and the operands are of different types*.

Since the type of `A()` is the same as the type of `A()`, the `+`-operation fails without consulting `__radd__`.

See also [the footnote](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#id20) on exactly this point

> For operands of the same type, it is assumed that if the non-reflected method – such as `__add__()` – fails then the overall operation is not supported, which is why *the reflected method is not called*.